# What is the canonical way of storing "global" information in Layout and Controller?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I have a Zend Framework based application that needs a bunch of information made available in multiple controllers and one global layout.

So my question is what might be the best/canonical way to get this information out of the Model layer and distribute them into the Controllers and the Layout as well.

I don't want to inherit from some kind of base controller. My thoughts go into the direction of Action Helpers or Plugins. I could store all the information I need into the layout and read it out from the view/layout in the controllers that need those information. But then again I don't find that solution very elegant.

Any thoughts or hints how to accomplish this in a clean way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For data that needs to be injected into a common area of a layout but not accessed in an action/view-script (sidebar; auth links like login, logout, register, profile; etc), I'd probably use a front-controller plugin.

However, if you need this data inside only some controller actions/viewscripts, then 
I'd go with an action-helpers with a `preDispatch()` hook that computes/holds your data. Make sure you register/instantiate this action helper at bootstrap so that it exists when the `preDispatch()` signal gets fired later on.

Then in your controller, the heavy lifting has already been done: pull the data from the action-helper and use it in the action or pass it through to your view-scripts.

Just thinking out loud...

Comment: I like that! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped. On further reflection, if you need results from the action-helper in only _some_ controllers/actions, then a `preDispatch()` hook is probably inadvisable since it will get fired on _every_ action, but used in only _some_ of them. Better might be to let the action-helper do its heavy lifting on demand, when called by the controllers/actions that need them.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like using the [Registry](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.registry.using.html) is a good approach for what you want.

Since it sounds like you have data you want to store for access, I think it makes more sense to store it in the registry rather than using helpers or plugins.

If you're concerned with naming of the objects in the registry, and having to remember and access the various keys all over your application, it could make sense to have plugin classes you can call that abstract the usage of Zend_Registry::get().

Comment: I thought about the Registry too. But I always try to avoid global state in my programs.

Comment: It's pretty acceptable to use in ZF, and I think part of the reason it was created was to provide a more controlled way of storing global data.

Comment: If it's always the same information the registry is great, I put my application.ini in the registry by default. For model information that changes during the application process a view helper would be the choice to dump model data directly to the view.